# Displaying a drupal page without the template around it in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I'd like to render the contents of a "basic page" in drupal. Something like this question: [displaying a Drupal view without a page template around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247991/displaying-a-drupal-view-without-a-page-template-around-it) but for Drupal 7.

My attempt almost works:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ( isset($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == 1 ) {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__ajax';
  }  
}
```

And have a file named `page--ajax.tpl.php` in the same directory where template.php lives:

```
<?php print $page['content']; ?>
```

The problem is that it still renders the menu and my two custom blocks from the sidebar. I only want the page content. What should I change?

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. The only thing you need is to add a custom HTML wrapper template.

- Add a function to `template.php`:

```php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ( isset($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == 1 ) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__ajax';
  }
}
```

- Create a file named `html--ajax.tpl.php`

```php
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

- Flush all caches. That's all.

Comment: The list item confused the parser. I entered the code from your link because there is nothing worse for future people than to find that the correct solution was here on a dead link :). I'll try your suggestion shortly and get back to you.

Comment: Please also try just <?php print $page; ?> without anything else (because this was a first version of the file ;) . Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I get the exact same output. I verified that both the `html--ajax` and `page--ajax` template is used (by printing HTML comments). The problem I think is that the blocks appear to be part of `$page['content']` in page--ajax, so they get rendered anyway.

Comment: Well anyway you need custom html template for ajax response. Do you use any base theme framework (i.e. zen, omega etc)?

Comment: Did you solve it? Actually I don't think your blocks output in $page['content'], maybe only if some module do this for you... Don't know if I can help you with this somehow without having a full project.

Comment: I couldn't solve it yet unfortunately. To be exact it is $page['content']['body'] I'm displaying. Interestingly, if I `print_r` the `$page['content']` array I get several items that have the content without blocks, but when I try to use them the blocks are added.

Comment: Answer number three is correct however there is a mysterious tick mark at the end of line two which is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 4):

> Based on the answer of Ufonion Labs I was able to completely remove
>   all the HTML output around the page content in Drupal 7 by
>   implementing both `hook_preprocess_page` and `hook_preprocess_html` in
>   my themes template.php, like this:
>
> ```
> function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
>   if (isset($_GET['response_type']) && $_GET['response_type'] == 'embed') {
>     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__embed';
>   }
> }
>
> function MY_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
>   if (isset($_GET['response_type']) && $_GET['response_type'] == 'embed') {
>     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__embed';
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Then I added two templates to my theme: `html--embed.tpl.php`:
>
> ```
> <?php print $page; ?>
> ```
>
> and `page--embed.tpl.php`:
>
> ```
> <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
> ```
>
> Now when I open a node page, such as http://example.com/node/3, I see
>   the complete page as usual, but when I add the response_type
>   parameter, such as http://example.com/node/3?response_type=embed, I
>   *only* get the `<div>` with the page contents so it can be embedded in another page.

Shamelessly taken form here :
[displaying a Drupal view without a page template around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247991/displaying-a-drupal-view-without-a-page-template-around-it) (second best answer for drupal 7).

Alexei solution still use the page template wich is in charge of displaying blocks