# Using theme_hook_suggestions in hook_preprocess_page stops html.tpl.php from being used

Tags: drupal-7

I've added this line to hook_preprocess_page in template.php:

```
if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type=='landing_page') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
}
```

This worked fine on my test server however now I have put it on staging and has caused:

A) Only the page template is output - it is not surrounded by html.tpl.php.

B) My preprocess_html function in template.php is not being called at all.

If I comment out the line then html.tpl.php is used again.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247991/displaying-a-drupal-view-without-a-page-template-around-it/8396968#8396968) is discussing similar but opposite problem.

I'm really stumped on this - any points would be really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by calling an undefined function in my page template.

This wasn't apparent until I started searching the error logs.

Hope this may save someone else some time...